# Angular 7 LazyLoading with children of children

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I may struggle to articulate the problem, but I do have a StackBlitz to help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brhyir

Notice the Lazyloading 'users'...

app.routes.ts

```
//import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SecureComponent } from './layouts/secure.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

//SECURE
export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '',
  component: HelloComponent,
  data: {
  }
},

//Lazyloading
{ path: 'users',
  data: {
  breadcrumb: 'Users',
},
loadChildren: './users/user.module#UserModule' }
];

export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: SecureComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, 
 children: SECURE_ROUTES },

];
```

this works, but...

user.routes. ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersComponent } from './users.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { UserTwoComponent } from './user/user-two.component';

export const UserRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '',
  component: UsersComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'user',
      component: UserComponent,
      data: {
        breadcrumb: 'New'
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: 'user2',
          component: UserTwoComponent,
          data: {
            breadcrumb: 'New2'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
];
```

So if you click the buttons you will witness the problem. Which is, the route is correct (users/user) BUT it does NOT load the 'UserComponent', instead it still shows the 'User**s**Component'. Why I do not know?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the template of any target components that will render child routes.

Both `UsersComponent` and `UserComponent` have no `<router-outlet>` to render other routes.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues:

1. In the users.component.ts, you need to make a small modification

   ```
   toUser() {
      this.router.navigate(['user'], {relativeTo: this.route});
   }
   ```

   This is needed to tell angular to route you to a certain path that is *relative* to the current path you are on.
2. Same thing in the user.component.ts,

   ```
   toUserTwo() {
      this.router.navigate(['user2'], {relativeTo: this.route});   
   }
   ```

   For both these points to work you need to inject the `ActivatedRoute` in the respective constructors. You need to import it from `@angular/router`
3. Next, you need to add the following in the user.component.html as well as the users.component.html

   ```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ```

   This is needed to render child routes in the parent template.

Here's the [stackblitz](https://angular-brhyir.stackblitz.io) if you need to see a working example of it.

Comment: Sure. Up the Reds!

Comment: I made a small edit while you were away. Make sure to add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to both user and users .html

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if it solves your problem. If people take the time to review off site source code they deserve some credit.

Comment: Hey, I don't want user one 'inside' the users component? And could I see your stackblitz in edit mode? to see the code...

Comment: Just to be a little more clear. I want to go from users -> user one -> user two  AND only show their respective templates. Hope that makes sense. That being said, I don't understand how to make this happen.

Comment: This really doesn't solve the issue, because it puts the 'user one' template INTO the 'users' template. Instead, we want each one to stand alone...

Comment: Well, I've tried to *articulate* it in the best way I could. However, you should be able to figure it out by following the above guidelines given by either of the answers.